# There are many spoty on my car

Tags: grammar

There are many spoty on my car.

The car was parked under a tree and the flower heart droped on the car.
Can we say "There are many spoty on my car."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say "There are many spots on my car." I'm not entirely sure if that's what you're trying to say, however.

Also, "droped" should be "dropped."

Answer (score 0):

You can say, "There are many spots on my car."

You can also say, "My car looks very spotty."

However, "There are many spoty on my car" would not be correct English.

From NOAD:

> **spotty** (*adj.*) marked with spots